# Java Security Manager grand permissions not working

Tags: java, exception, accesscontrolexception

Java code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] agrs)  {
        System.out.print("123");
    }
}
```

Policy:

```
grant codeBase "file:/Users/workspace/test/src/*" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

JVM arg:

```
  -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=my.policy
```

When running java code, still got access denied exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:128)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:146)
break in console is not supported due to security permissions: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "idea.launcher.bin.path" "read")
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: .policy and .java files are both in the directory of : /Users/workspace/test/src/

Comment: same exception if using ==

Comment: Are you getting the above exception while running some class that uses reflection or while running the java code you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Beacuse the stack trace has `java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission`

Comment: I'm running in the java code I provided. I'm using intellij IDE, os system